# nginx stop process to app, return 400 bad request

Tags: php, node.js, nginx, url-routing

if url with un encode string like `tag/100%/`  browser get 400 bad request message from nginx.

How to force  without check specific parameter encode, just continue the process to app ( node.js, php )?

php app config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain2.com.localhost www.domain2.com.localhost;
access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/domain2.com.access.log;
root /Users/user/Sites/domain2.com/;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
client_max_body_size 1G;

location /robots.txt {
alias /Users/user/Sites/domain2.com/app/robots.txt;
}
location ~^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
root /Users/user/Sites/domain2.com/app/assets;
access_log off;
expires max;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_index index.php;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
}
}
```

nodejs app config

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com.localhost  www.domain.com.localhost;
access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/domain.com.access.log;
location /robots.txt {
alias /Users/user/Sites/domain.com/app/robots.txt;
}
location ~ ^/(images/|javascripts/|stylesheets/|fonts) {
root /Users/user/Sites/domain.com/app/assets;
access_log off;
expires max;
}
location / {
set $fixed_destination $http_destination;
if ( $http_destination ~* ^https(.*)$ )
{
set $fixed_destination http$1;
}
proxy_pass http://127.00.0.1:8002/;

proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Destination $fixed_destination;

client_max_body_size 32M;
client_body_buffer_size 512k;
proxy_connect_timeout 300;
proxy_send_timeout 300;
proxy_read_timeout 300;
proxy_buffer_size 4k;
proxy_buffers 4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
}
}
```